# Reduce Windows 8 resources consumption and raising explorer

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, windows-8, internet-explorer-11

I'm running some local application on a mini-PC and lately it has started freezing about once a week. When it's freezing the OS seems to still respond (most of the times). Internet explorer freezing with the message that "Internet Explorer is not responding".

The application is built using HTML/JS/PHP and MySQL. It runs on Internet Explorer using WAMP. (Assume that there is no way to modify the application at the moment).

I want to to find a way to reduce Windows 8.1 resource consumption to minimum. It won't matter how the graphic may look. If possible, only leave the necessary services for running Internet explorer and the localhost application.

I want to take those saved resources and "invest" them in Internet Explorer.

I believe this solution will solve, or at least improve the behavior of the application because when the application is ran on a stronger PC, it simply never crashes even without doing anything to the OS.

Also, if there is a way to do your suggestion with a CMD command so I can make a handy .bat file, it will be great.

Comment: Have you investigated the drivers and/or enabled plugins on the mini-PC?  I've frequently found that updating (or disabling) Flash, along with verifying/updating video drivers (or disabling hardware acceleration in IE), and updating/disabling browser add-ons helps tremendously.

Assuming, of course, you've got enough RAM in the first place (at least 2GB, depending on the version of Windows).

Comment: @LanceLeonard Hey, the mini-PC has 4GB of RAM. It has no dedicated GPU but just a CPU with graphics built-in. I will try to also disable flash. Why disabling hardware acceleration in IE would make it better? wouldn't it be the opposite?

Comment: Normally, it would be better performance-wise, however, graphic drivers are somewhat notorious for, um, needing updates.  The behavior you're describing sounds a lot like memory leakage and drivers/add-ons are the most common sources.  At the very least, disabling them helps you narrow things down a bit.  (Remember to also apply all outstanding updates and reboot.)  If you determine that the behavior remains when hardware acceleration is disabled, then re-enable it by all means.  The point is to try to find the source of the problem and then look for the fix.

Comment: @LanceLeonard I see. Should I disable graphic acceleration in Windows 8.1 OS, or maybe just in Internet Explorer? Maybe both? By the way, how do I disable it?

Comment: Well, since it seems to be IE that's displaying the problem, it's probably best to limit initial research to that.  To disable hardware acceleration in IE, go to Internet Options, open the Advanced tab, and then locate the Accelerated graphics setting.  In IE11, the checkbox is titled "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering."  Check that, choose OK, and then restart the browser.  If the problem continues, you know the problem isn't the video drivers and can undo the setting change.

Comment: @LanceLeonard I see. Well I will try it, thanks :) I will need at leat a week to test it, unfortunately :/ I will let you know what the results were!